# std::set insert with initialiser lists

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution

I have this simple code:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy){}
    bool operator<(const Base& b) const {return (x < b.x) || (x==b.x && y < b.y);}

    int x;
    int y;
};

struct D1 : Base
{
    D1(int x, int y) : Base(x, y){}
};

struct D2 : Base
{
    D2(int x = 0, int y = 0) : Base(x, y){}
};

void test()
{
    std::set<D1> s1;
    std::set<D2> s2;

    s1.insert({1, 2});
    s2.insert({1, 2});

    std::cout<<"s1 size:"<<s1.size()<<std::endl<<"Content:"<<std::endl;
    for(auto& v : s1)
    {
        std::cout<<v.x<<" "<<v.y<<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<std::endl<<"s2 size:"<<s2.size()<<std::endl<<"Content:"<<std::endl;
    for(auto& v : s2)
    {
        std::cout<<v.x<<" "<<v.y<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
s1 size:1
Content: 
1 2

s2 size:2
Content:
1 0
2 0
```

Why is the behaviour different when inserting objects with default arguments? Is this a bug or is it the intended behaviour?

PS: You can see the code in action here: https://ideone.com/UPArOi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb here is that the `initializer_list<X>` overloads are **strongly preferred** to other overloads.

First, from [over.ics.list]

> if the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` and all the elements of the initializer list can
>   be implicitly converted to `X`, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an
>   element of the list to `X`, or if the initializer list has no elements, the identity conversion. This conversion can
>   be a user-defined conversion even in the context of a call to an initializer-list constructor.

And, from [over.ics.rank]:

> List-initialization sequence L1 is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence L2 if
>   — L1 converts to `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and L2 does not [...]

We have two relevant overloads of [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert):

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value );
void insert( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );
```

For the first call:

```
s1.insert({1, 2});
```

Consider the overload with parameter type `std::initializer_list<D1>`. Neither `1` nor `2` can be implicitly converted to `D1`, so that overload is not viable. Now consider the `D1&&` overload. Since we can construct a `D1` with that initializer list, that's the overload that's selected, and we end up with a single element: `D1{1, 2}`.

However, in this case:

```
s2.insert({1, 2});
```

Both `1` and `2` *can* be implicitly converted to `D2`, thanks to the default argument in `D2`'s constructor. So the `initializer_list<D2>` overload is viable. The `D2&&` overload is viable as well, but the `initializer_list` conversion sequence is a better conversion sequence, so it's preferred. This gives us *two* elements, `D2{1}` and `D2{2}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior.  It's because you're using an `initialization list` to `insert` into your `set`. What that does for your default args is to create two objects with each `int` (using the defaulted value for the second arg).